# Directional? moments of multivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, integration, gaussian-integral

Here's the thing :) Let $X\sim N_n(\vec{0}, \Sigma)$ be a multivariate normal random variable (centered) of dimension $n\geq 1$. Here, $\Sigma$ denotes the covariance matrix.

My question is: Is it possible to compute (or bound) the directional centered absolute moments? I.e.

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |x_1|^{p_1}\cdots |x_n|^{p_n} p_{\Sigma}(x_1,\dots,x_n)dx_1\cdots dx_n,$$
where
$$p_{\Sigma}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (2\pi)^{-n/2} |\Sigma|^{-1/2} \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} x^t \Sigma^{-1} x\right\}$$
denotes the density function and $|\Sigma|$ the determinant of $\Sigma$ and $p_1,\dots,p_n$ are positive real numbers.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: If the $p_i$ are even integers, the answer is merely messy, but otherwise the problem is also very difficult.  Unless, say, $\Sigma$ is diagonal.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Higher_moments for even integers case

Comment: Is there a way to make them all even, or assume they are even without loss of generality? Of course Hölder inequality $n$-times could be useful but it is a very rough inequality when applied so many times.

Or for example, if all $p_i$'s are even and I can estimate the RHS, does the same estimate also hold for $p_i$'s that are smaller?